# Facing Issue "configure: error: cannot find headers for leveldb" while building the leveldb Java Wrapper (fusesource / leveldbjni) 1.8.1

Tags: c++, c, linux, maven, leveldb

I am trying to build leveldbjni 1.8.1 version with leveldb version 1.22, snappy-1.1.8 .
OS: RHEL 7.4

## Dependencies:

gcc , g++ version : 4.8.5

LevelDB 1.22 was built using Cmake 3.9.0

I am facing the below issue during maven build of project leveldbjni-linux64 . Can you please help us resolve this.

## Error:

```
[INFO] executing: /bin/sh -c ./configure --disable-ccache --prefix=/tmp/leveldbjni/leveldbjni-linux64/target/native-build/target --with-leveldb=/tmp/leveldb-1.22 --with-snappy=/tmp/snappy-1.1.8
[INFO] configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --disable-ccache
[INFO] checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
.
.
.
[INFO] checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
[INFO] checking if g++ static flag -static works... no
[INFO] checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
[INFO] checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
[INFO] checking whether the g++ linker (/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
[INFO] checking dynamic linker characteristics... (cached) GNU/Linux ld.so
[INFO] checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
[INFO] checking the archiver (ar) interface... ar
[INFO] configure: javac was on your path, checking to see if it's part of a JDK we can use...
[INFO] checking if '/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_201-amd64' is a JDK... yes
[INFO] checking pthread.h usability... yes
[INFO] checking pthread.h presence... yes
[INFO] checking for pthread.h... yes
[INFO] checking leveldb/db.h usability... no
[INFO] checking leveldb/db.h presence... yes
[INFO] configure: WARNING: leveldb/db.h: present but cannot be compiled
[INFO] configure: WARNING: leveldb/db.h: check for missing prerequisite headers?
[INFO] configure: WARNING: leveldb/db.h: see the Autoconf documentation
[INFO] configure: WARNING: leveldb/db.h: section "Present But Cannot Be Compiled"
[INFO] configure: WARNING: leveldb/db.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
[INFO] checking for leveldb/db.h... no
[INFO] configure: error: cannot find headers for leveldb
[INFO] rc: 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] leveldbjni 1.8.1 ................................... SUCCESS [ 3.538 s]
[INFO] leveldbjni-linux64 1.8 ............................. FAILURE [ 2.786 s]
[INFO] leveldbjni-project 99-master-SNAPSHOT .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.630 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-12-30T12:20:09+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.fusesource.hawtjni:maven-hawtjni-plugin:1.9:build (default) on project leveldbjni-linux64: build failed: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: ./configure failed with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.fusesource.hawtjni:maven-hawtjni-plugin:1.9:build (default) on project leveldbjni-linux64: build failed: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: ./configure failed with exit code: 1
```

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow! Could you add your precise question here as well?

Comment: I see the maven build of leveldbjni-linux64 failing because the script "executing: /bin/sh -c ./configure --disable-ccache --prefix=/tmp/leveldbjni/leveldbjni-linux64/target/native-build/target --with-leveldb=/tmp/leveldb-1.22 --with-snappy=/tmp/snappy-1.1.8" failed with rc 1.
Please help analyse the root cause .